# Problem for extract data of array PHP

Tags: php

Necesito extraer de un objeto el campo body , estoy tratando de la siguiente forma

```
 $mensaje= $data2->{'messages'}[0]->{'body'}
```

pero no he podido obtenerlo, adjunto la estructura que debo obtener

```
array(2) {
  ["messages"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(9) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(74) "false_17472822486@c.us_DF38E6A25B42CC8CCE57EC40F_DF38E6A25B42CC8CCE57EC40F"
      ["body"]=>
      string(6) "Hello."
      ["type"]=>
      string(4) "chat"
      ["senderName"]=>
      string(4) "Ilya"
      ["fromMe"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["author"]=>
      string(16) "17472822486@c.us"
      ["time"]=>
      int(1504208593)
      ["chatId"]=>
      string(16) "17472822486@c.us"
      ["messageNumber"]=>
      int(100)
    }
```

Comment: `$data2['mensajes'][0]['body']`

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero sería corregir el termino objecto, ya que lo que muestras es un array.
Siendo así este se debe tratar como tal.

Suponiendo esto tu array tiene esta estructura

```
$data["messages"][0]["id"] = "false_17472822486@c.us_DF38E6A25B42CC8CCE57EC40F_DF38E6A25B42CC8CCE57EC40F";
$data["messages"][0]["body"] = "Hello";
```

Entonces para poder mostrar, en este caso el valor del body debes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
echo $data["messages"][0]["body"]; // Hello
```

Saludos